# Create own IVR that will access Database

Tags: python, database, asterisk, twilio, ivr

I'm currently interning with a company and have been tasked with researching some methods of using telephony. The goal is to provide our clients with the ability to call in and through an IVR-prompted questions, get information back. The information will be from our database.

I have successfully done this using Twilio and a small python app. It does exactly what I'm looking to do, except the cost factor can be a bit high, especially if we have 30,000+ clients calling for minutes on end.

My goal is to find a way to replicate what I've done with Twilio, but on our own server. I've found options like Asterisk and IncrediblePBX, but because my limited knowledge of Linux, every error I run into results in scouring the internet for answers. Ultimately, I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction.

This is an example of what I'd like to accomplish:

Client calls into number. They're directed to provide an account number, (possibly their phone number) At that point it will take this information and talk to a database. Gathering this information it will relay back to the client the status of their account etc.

Questions:
I was hoping to use Google Voice to route calls similar to Twilio, is this possible? Alternatively, could my company switch to a VoIP and do the same thing?

If I move away from Twilio, can Asterisk perform the necessary tasks? Receiving calls and running the app to gather database information.

Current code for Twilio, in Python:

```js
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
 
app = Flask(__name__)
callers = {
    "+": "Nicholas",
}
 
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def initial():
    # Get the caller's phone number from the incoming Twilio request
    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
 
    # if the caller is someone we know:
    if from_number in callers:
        # Greet the caller by name
        caller = callers[from_number]
    else:
        caller = ""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.say("Hello " + caller)
    resp.say("Thank you for calling.")
    your_number = list(from_number)
    del your_number[0]
    del your_number[0]
    resp.say("You are calling from: ")
    x = 0
    while x < len(your_number):
        resp.say(your_number[x])
        x += 1

    print("Please enter the neighborhood I.D. you're looking for.")
    with resp.gather(numDigits=1, action="/handle-first", method="POST") as g:
     g.say("Please enter the neighborhood I.D. you're looking for.")

    return str(resp)

@app.route("/handle-first", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_key():
    digit_pressed = request.values.get('Digits', '')
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    url = 'http://localhost/...'
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.readall().decode('utf-8'))   
    current = data['rows'][0]['Neighborhood']
    print(current)
    resp.say("You have chosen " + current + "as your neighborhood.")
    with resp.gather(numDigits=1, action="/handle-second", method="POST") as h:
        h.say("Press 1 to choose another Neighborhood?")

    return str(resp)

@app.route("/handle-second", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_key2():
    digit_pressed = request.values.get('Digits', '')
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    if digit_pressed == "1":
        return redirect("/")

    else:
        resp.say("Thank you for calling. Good-bye.")
        return str(resp)

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hey Nicholas, I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio. Can you drop me an email (philnash@twilio.com) and we can have a bit more of a chat about this? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk is fundamentally different than Twilio, I can honestly say they are somewhat opposites. The track you are seeking to follow is that of Asterisk dialplan with a combination of AGI. AGI is the Asterisk Gateway Interface, and will enable you a way to interact with Asterisk via a simple scripting mechanism. The API is fairly simple and there is a whole range of ready made libraries you can use. Let's put it this way, when it comes to AGI, just pick your poison - PHP, Python, JAVA, Ruby - all are available.

My personal favorite, and many in the Asterisk world as well, is PHP - with an LGPL component called PHP-AGI. It's fairly old and has been around for years, but works well with all versions of Asterisk. If you wish to walk on the bleeding edge and require stronger call control, you can go with ARI (Asterisk REST interface), however, judging from your requirement - that's an overkill.

You can read a bit about AGI development with PHP at this link:

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/asterisk-gateway-interface-scripting-php

(Shameful plug - I wrote the book)

In addition, you can refer to the following presentation for additional information (again, my own presentation) - It's a little old, but still valid in terms of concept and usage:

http://osdc.org.il/2006/html/Asterisk_AGI_Programming.ppt

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for this information. Do you have any recommendations on which Linux distro to use? I've been using centOS. Would FreePBX and Asterisk help in the overall functionality of this? What about AsteriskNOW?

Comment: Hi Nichloas,  To be honest, FreePBX isn't my favorite distribution - somewhat bloated to my taste, but again, I'm a developer and prefer something cleaner. Regardless of that, my OS preference was (and probably will be) CentOS - but again, that's me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, asterisk can do all task you can program. It even have api for access raw stream.

However no, you can't use SAME code.

For google voice check chan_motif code.

For db access use dialplan+realtime or func_odbc or fastagi/agi interface.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for an open source IVR solution. The only one I am aware of is [OpenVBX](http://www.openvbx.org/).

I am in no way affiliate with them or Twilio.